# Database modeling for a weak entity

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I have 2 tables in my database `orders` and `orderHistory`.

```
 -----------------                    -----------------------
 |  orders       |                    |  orderHistory       |
 -----------------                    -----------------------
 | orderID  (PK) |                    | historyLineID  (PK) |
 | orderDate     |                    | status              |
 | price         |                    | quantity            |
 -----------------                    -----------------------
```

Now an `order` can have multiple `history lines`. However, a `history line` can't exist on its own. I heard this is called a weak entity and therefore the **PK** from `orders` must be part of the **PK** of table `orderHistory`.

**Questions**

1. Is this really a correct *weak entity* relationship? Is there other ways to identify them?
2. Should I add the **PK** of table `order` to table `orderHistory` and make it a composite primary key?
3. In case I decide to add a new record to `orderHistory`, how will I add a new composite key? (`orderID` is available from table `orders`, but `historyLineID` should be auto incremented.)
4. What if I decide to model this as a normal **One-To-Many** relationship where `orderID` is added as a foreign key **only** instead? what are the cons of doing so?
5. Will ignoring Weak entities at all cause any problems later in a design provided all tables are in 3rd normal form?

**Note**

Both `orderID` & `historyLineID` are surrogate keys.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An entity is not weak because it can't exist independently, but because it can't be **identified** independently. Therefore, a relationship that "leads" to a weak entity is called "identifying" relationship. In practice, this means that the parent's primary key is migrated into (usually [proper](http://www.mathwords.com/p/proper_subset.htm)) subset of child's PK (the term "weak entity" is usually defined in relation to primary keys, though it could in theory apply to any key).

It is perfectly legit to have an entity that can't exist independently, but can be identified independently - in other words, that is in a non-identifying relationship to a non-NULL.

You have to ask: can `historyLineID` be unique **alone**, or in combination with `orderID`? I suspect the latter is the case, which would make it a weak entity.

> Is this really a correct weak entity relationship?

What you have shown us isn't a weak entity - parent's PK is not migrated into the child's PK.

> Is there other ways to identify them?

You have essentially two options:

- `orderHistory` has a composite PK: `{orderID, historyLineID}`, where `orderID` is FK. BTW, this PK could be considered "natural":

  [image]
- `orderHistory` has a surrogate PK: `{orderHistoryID}`, while `orderID` is outside of the PK. You'd still need to have an alternate key `{orderID, historyLineID}` though:

  [image]

> Should I add the PK of table order to table orderHistory and make it a composite primary key?

Yes, this is the first option described above. Unless you have child relationships on `orderHistory` itself, this is also the best solution. If `orderHistory` does have children, than this may or may not be the best solution, depending on several factors.

> What if I decide to model this as a normal One-To-Many relationship where orderID is added as a foreign key instead? what are the cons of doing so?

This is not either-or. A field can be both FK and a part of a (primary or alternate) key, as shown above.

> Will ignoring Weak entities at all cause any problems later in a design provided all tables are in 3rd normal form?

You won't be able to reach 3NF unless you specify your keys correctly, and you won't be able to do that without considering which entity can be identified independently and which can't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Just to understand exactly what you meant by: "_An entity is not weak because it can't exist independently, but because it can't be identified independently._", what if I have 2 tables `customers` & `orders`? A **Customer** can have many **Orders**, but an **Order** belongs to only one **Customer**. I have modeled this into 2 tables where the **CustomerID** is added to the **Orders** table as a **FK** only. However, now when I think about it The **Order** by itself has no meaning if it isn't made by a **Customer**. Should **Orders** by a weak entity?

Comment: @Songo How do you identify order? If customer's PK is within order's PK, then it's weak. If it isn't then it's not. In both cases, order cannot exist without customer.

Comment: well I created a surrogate primary key `OrderID` for the table `Orders`. I never thought about weak entities before, so for every entity I had I just created a surrogate key to _identify_ them. If I need to relate entities I just used foreign keys (**1-1**, **1-M** & **M-M**). I'm not sure now what _identify_ really means :D

Comment: @Songo What is means is actually described in the 3rd paragraph of my answer. You essentially have to figure out if given field(s) can be unique alone, or you need to combine it with parent's PK. In the case of order, if OrderID alone is unique (which I'm guessing is the case), then order is not a weak entity. BTW, don't just create surrogates indiscriminately. InnoDB is clustered and alternate indexes are expensive in clustered tables, so if you can live **just** with a "natural" composite PK (and 1 index), this is usually better than having both surrogate and natural key (and 2 indexes).

Comment: hmmm I see your point. So basically if I add a surrogate auto increment ID field to all my tables (like I always did) then I'll never have weak entities, right?

Comment: @Songo Depends on how you define the term "weak entity". If you define it in relation to primary keys, then you'll never have a weak entity. If you define it in relation to any key, then nothing will change - weak entities will remain weak since you'll still need the same keys,  they will just be alternate instead of primary.

Comment: Well I think the question now is when to not add a surrogate ID field to a table? Most books I read defined PK as: _column or more that can uniquely identify a row_. However, they always stated that one column key is better than a composite key. Also for better indexing the single column should be an integer. They then introduce the concept of surrogate key as a better solution than using a natural key. That was clearly stated in [Database Design for Mere Mortals: A Hands-On Guide to Relational Database Design](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Relational/dp/0201694719)

Comment: @Songo _If_ that book states that, then find another book. It is absolutely not true that surrogates are **always** better than naturals, nor is the opposite always true. Each has strengths and weaknesses and you should choose accordingly. Right tool for the job, remember?

Comment: @Songo BTW, that's a definition of a key, not just primary key.

Comment: +1 Well, It seems my understanding for the Weak Entity concept was originally wrong :) Thank you for the detailed answer. BTW can you recommend good Database modelling Books? Ones that discusses such topics in great detail? I read Database for mere mortals and [Database Modeling and Design, Fifth Edition Logical Design](http://www.amazon.com/Database-Modeling-Design-Fifth-Edition/dp/0123820200)

Comment: @Songo Take a look at [ERwin Methods Guide](http://tangra.si.umich.edu/~radev/654/resources/ERMGALL.PDF) and [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a weak entity relationship because of the reliance, but it is essentially an instance of indecisiveness. An order may have one to many history lines, but each history line must have a orderID, correct?

It sounds like an optional-mandatory relationship.
 So your orderId has "optional" attributes in orderHistory...
2. You can partly solve the problem by making the primary key a composition of orderID and historyLineID
3. You will have to do a involuted relationship on the orderID table. so you will have to join back on the order.orderID and then create the new historyLineID, otherwise you cannot create on something that doesn't exist yet.
4. This is the way it should be. It is much easier to understand this way for future people working on the script, and probably yourself. Use the foreign key to create an orderID (parent) with multiple historyLineID's (children), because the order can have multiple order lines, this method would probably be the best.

LINK: [enter link description here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Development-Cycles/Entity-Relationship-Modeling/9/)