# Database structuration suggestions for a poll web app

Tags: mysql, sql

Im designing a poll application, where the user creates one or several polls whith questions and predefined answers for each question, so far no problem, im thinking the easiest way to do this is with 3 tables:

Polls Table:

```
id title description
```

Questions table:

```
id poll_id question
```

Answers table:

> id question_id answer

The problem is, the user may select a different behavior on the questioning flow of the poll, for example a normal poll will go from question 1 to question N (being N the final question), but in my case the user may want if the user choose answer 2 of question 4 to jump to question 7 and ignore the rest between them.

Im a bit confuse about how to store in database this behavior, any suggestions?

Comment: Can I suggest you start with your business classes and work backwards to the persistence layer. Going the other way may lock you in to a straight-jacket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Answer > NextQuestion table    

AnswerID    NextQuestionID
```

Based on your answer, the next question is defined in here

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

[image]

Look at the construction of keys here:

- The QUESTION is in [identifying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658665/533120) relationship with POLL and the resulting natural key provides not just uniqueness but ordering as well: QUESTION_NO can monotonically increase while keeping the same POLL_ID.
- The equivalent effect is accomplished by ANSWER_NO in POSSIBLE_ANSWER.
- The user can pick at most one answer for any given question. That's why ANSWER_NO is **outside** of the ACTUAL_ANSWER primary key.
- On the other hand, USER_ID is kept inside the ACTUAL_ANSWER PK, to allow the same answer to be picked by more than one user.
- Theoretically, there should be a key in QUESTION_TABLE on {POLL_ID, QUESTION_TEXT}, to prevent two different questions having the same text in the same poll. However, QUESTION_TEXT might be long and is potentially implemented as BLOB, which most DBMSes can't index or constrain by a key. The similar dilemma exists for POSSIBLE_ANSWER.ANSWER_TEXT.

If user skips a question, just omit the corresponding ACTUAL_ANSWER.