# How to store 3 pictures and one song for an artist entity?

Tags: database-design

I have an **Artist** entity. An artist can have 3 pictures maximum (and one minimum) and one song with its title.

So  my **first idea** was to store the pictures in a separate table **Picture** with id, artist_id, path.

And to store the song in a **Song** entity with id, artist_id, path, title

But **another idea** would be to store these media in a **Media** table with id, artiste_id, picture1, picture2, picture3, path_song, title_song.

What is the best way to do it?

Any help would be great!

Comment: whichever is easier for you. but i d prefer the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the most precise way to model your **current** requirements would be to store 3 pictures and 1 song directly as fields in the Artist table. In that scenario, there would be very little need to vertically split the Artist and make a separate Media table.

---

The only question is: are you **sure** you will never need more than 3 pictures and more than one song? If not, do the first approach, but I'd modify it in the following way:

[image]

```
CHECK (PICTURE_NO BETWEEN 1 AND 3)
CHECK (SONG_NO = 1)
```

The combination of [identifying relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658665/533120) and CHECKs ensure the desired *maximums* are honored. If you need to grow, just modify (or completely remove) the CHECKs.

Unfortunately, *minimums* (the presence of at least one picture and song) cannot be guaranteed in this model, at least not without resorting to deferred circular references, which are probably more trouble than they're worth even if your DBMS supports them.

---

And of course, in the real life, there may be multiple artists involved in a piece of art. Are you sure the relationship is 1:N and not N:N?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed and clear answer. I appreciate it a lot. Yes, it's sure the relationship is 1:N because it is a for a contest and they can't participate in another artist's piece of art. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

From a database normalization perspective, your first idea is the better one.