# Database Design: Storing previous version versus storing first version in version control systems

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am really new to using databases and database design/creating schemas and I'd really appreciate some advice/suggestions. I am creating an application where users enter data and I'm providing version control for that data to the users. Users can go in and revert changes or update values (sort of like git), etc and I am creating a database structure to store these values. Currently I have two different possibilities in mind, however I am not sure which one has more advantages.

***First possibility: Store pointer to previous version***

**Data_Table**

id IntegerField

data_content TextField

version_control_first_version  ForeignKeyField(Data_Version_Control_Table)

**Data_Version_Control_Table**

id IntegerField

previous_version SelfReferentialForeignKey Nullable

In the first possibility, I store a link to the previous version of the data in the version control table. As new versions start pouring in, I create new rows in the Version Control table and for each of them, I link the row to the previous version's row. The Data Table only holds the newest version of the data (I've decided to hold the current version in a different table as this is the best approach for my use case and the version control table should be significantly larger than the current version table as there are a lot of entries there).

***Second Possibility: Store pointer to root/first version***

**Data_Table**

id IntegerField

data_content TextField

version_control_first_version ForeginKeyField(Data_Version_Control_Table)

**Data_Version_Control_Table**

id IntegerField

first_version SelfReferentialForeignKey Nullable

version_number IntegerField

For this design, for all versions of the same data, I store a pointer to the first version of the data rather than the previous version and a version number. When I want to rollback to a particular version, I jump the number of versions that I need to, to get to the version I'm looking for. That's the only difference here and the rest is pretty much the same. I might also add that I am storing the date time that these versions were created as well if that might help.

Are there any significant advantages or disadvantages with these options that would justify using one over the other? Will I take a performance hit if I use one over the other? Which one will allow faster and easier queries and which one is the optimal model? Are there any flaws with any of these models?

Thanks for your help in advance and have a wonderful day :)

Comment: What use is the first version if you want to be able to roll back? You would need the previous version for that, right?

Comment: Have a look at the chapter "Samples of data structures -- Chronological data" of the book ["Programming with databases"](https://www.amazon.com/dp/2956300806/).

Comment: @GolezTrol sorry, i forgot to mention that i also store the version number which means i can rollback to any version in the database. Will update the question

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you are trying to emulate pointers within a relational database, which:

- Isn't readily enforceable through database constraints. For example, you can't *declaratively* guarantee that the `version_control_first_version` or `first_version` really points to the first version or that the `previous_version` doesn't form branches or cycles.
- Doesn't really fit very well with how indexes work. For example, traversing the "linked list" of `previous_version` would require either a recursive CTE or repetitive querying. The ˙first_version` is better in this regard, but still unnecessarily complicated.

It would be better, IMO, to just make the version table a [weak entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658665/533120):

```
CREATE TABLE Data_Table (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
    -- Other fields...
);

CREATE TABLE Data_Version_Control_Table (
    id INT REFERENCES Data_Table,
    version_number INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, version_number)
    -- Other fields...
);
```

And then:

- The first version can be efficiently identified by finding `MIN(version_number)` for the given `id`. MIN/MAX is efficient to find in a B-Tree, essentially equivalent to an index seek.
- The previous version can also be efficiently found (by searching for the previous `version_number`). This is just an index seek.
- All versions of the same object can be efficiently found by searching for object's `id`. This is just an index range scan, no need for "list traversal" (and as a bonus, versions are already in the correct order).